# Ratchet Websocket pass a userID

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, websocket, ratchet

I'm wondering if I could pass an ID on this script

```
<script>
    var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8081/');
  conn.onopen = function(e) {
      console.log("Connection established!");
  };

  conn.onmessage = function(e) {
      console.log(e.data);
  };
</script>
```

and send a userid when creating the variable as such

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8081/', <?= $userid ?>);
```

Is it possible? if it is, how do you use the data on the server side?
is it onOpen or is it somewhere else?

I'm totally new to Ratchet and websockets in general, but I'm trying to use ratchet on my Codeigniter4 project, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using websocket [send()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications#sending_data_to_the_server) function.

So It would go somethign like this:

```
<script>
    var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8081/');
  conn.onopen = function(e) {
      console.log("Connection established!");
  };

  conn.onmessage = function(e) {
      console.log(e.data);
  };

  // send user id to the server
  conn.send(<?= $userid ?>);
</script>
```

Comment: Its that simple and I missed it, well what I need is actually a bit more than this, but your solution opens up my mind and think about filtering the message sent to the server rather than dividing 'chatrooms' with userid, helps a lot!